# How to inject parent component service into dynamic component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-dependency-injection

I am using Angular 8 and I have dynamically created component. I have parent component with the service into providers array. How I can inject the same instance of parent `MyService` into a dynamic component? Without dynamic component I can achieve it just by injecting into the constructor of the child component that service. But how I can do it with dynamic component? Here is the code of creating dynamic component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    providers: [MyService],
})
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private myService: MyService,
    ) {
    }

    createDynamicComponent() {
        const injector: Injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
                    useValue: getMatDateFormat(this.dateFormat),
                },
            ],
        })
        this.dynamicPlaceholder.clear()
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent)
        const componentRef = this.dynamicPlaceholder
            .createComponent(componentFactory, 0, injector)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in these lines:

```
const injector: Injector = Injector.create({
      providers: [
         {
            provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
            useValue: getMatDateFormat(this.dateFormat),
         },
      ],
})
```

I created a dynamic component injector from scratch. So it didn't know anything about parent injector. As a result - don't know about parent providers.
All I need to do - is add `parent` parameter to the `Injector.create` function:

```
const injector: Injector = Injector.create({
          providers: [
             {
                provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
                useValue: getMatDateFormat(this.dateFormat),
             },
          ],
          parent: this.injector
})
```

Where `this.injector` is injected into the constructor of the parent component:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
}
```